# Magento doesn't recognize module

Tags: magento2, module

I have created a new module but when I run the command `magento module:status` I couldn't see my module name either in the enabled or disabled list

my registeration.php code :

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Demo_Helloworld',
   __DIR__
);
```

the module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_Helloworld" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

why I can't see my module name in the module list?

Comment: your `registration.php` is called `registeration`?

Comment: yes that is true, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change Your File name **registeration.php** to  **registration.php** and run

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento module:status`